# Can I write the following limits?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

Let us consdier the following functions. We know some of their features as below.

> The functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are real, finite and continuous for all $x$ in $(a,b)$ and $f(x_0)= g(x_0)=0$ for $a <x_0<b$.
>   $h(x)$ is finite and always continous in the region $x\in(a,b)$, and

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}f_t(x)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_0^t F(x)dx=f(x)$$
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}g_t(x)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_0^t G(x)dx=g(x)$$
$$f(x)=g(x)·h(x).$$

**THE QUESTION**:

1-) Can I write the following limit?

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=h(x_0)$$

2-) Then again, can I write

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}f_t(x)=\lim_{t\to \infty}g_t(x)·h(x) \Rightarrow\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{f_t(x_0)}{g_t(x_0)}=h(x_0)?$$

Comment: The answer to 1) is NO since every neighborhood of $x_0$ may contain zeros of $g$. I don't understand the  notation in 2). What does the subsciprt $t$ stand for?

Comment: For question 1, what about  $$\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cdot \cos x$$ . We can write easily $$\tag{4}\lim_{x\to π}\frac {{\sin(2x)}}{ { \sin x}}=2\cos(π)$$

Comment: @Kavi, please look again, also the notation in 2-)

Comment: I am not thinking like Kavi Rama.  According to me ,   1. question  is definitely can be written.  The main issue is on 2. question .  Any comment  or answer  friends

Comment: $0$ is not allowed in the denominator of  a ratio. How do you know that $\frac {f(x)} {g(x)}$ even makes sense for all $x$ near $x_0$?

Comment: Becasue , The functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are  finite and continuous for all $x$ in $(a,b)$ and $f(x_0)= g(x_0)=0$ for $a <x_0<b$.  
$h(x)$ is finite and always continous in the region $x\in(a,b)$,   Or think x²-1=(x-1)(x+1)⇒lim((x²-1)/(x-1))

Comment: The equatoin $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ may be satisfied with $h(x)$ finite and $f(x)=g(x)=0$. So we cannot write $\frac {f(x)}{ g(x)}$ ,

Comment: What about the following one, I have given to you two examples ,   $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=2$$  Can you give at least one example.

Comment: Let $g(x)=x\sin (\frac  1 x)$ for $x \neq 0$, $g(0)=0$. Then $g$ is continuous, $g(0)=0$ and $g(\frac  1 {n\pi})=0$ for all $n$. So there are points arbitrarily close to $0$ where $g$ vanishes.

Comment: Please give an example , why can we  not write the formula in  1. question?.  But all $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ must be continuous. Please be aware here, there is always a limit result as $h(x_0)$

Comment: Sorry, your example is not suitable for   $f(x)=g(x)·h(x)$    give an example like  $sin2x=2sinx.cosx$   which valid for all $x$.